# Why can't I access a property of an object in a loaded array of objects in typescript?

Tags: arrays, typescript, object, properties, undefined

So, I cannot wrap my mind around this problem...

Basically, I have some variables and a constructor in a class:

```
currentUser: UserModel | null = null;
currentServer: ServerModel | null = null;
serverMembers: UserModel[] = [];

constructor(
  private modalService: MdbModalService,
  private userDataProvider: UserDataProvider,
  private serverDataProvider: ServerDataProvider
) {
  this.currentUser = this.userDataProvider.getCurrentUser();

  this.serverDataProvider
    .loadServerMembers()
    .pipe(
      mergeMap((members) => from(members)),
      mergeMap((member) => this.userDataProvider.getUserById(member.id)),
      toArray(),
      tap((resolvedMembers) => {
        console.log(resolvedMembers);
        console.log(resolvedMembers[0]);
        console.log(resolvedMembers[0].userName);
        this.serverMembers = resolvedMembers;
      })
    )
    .subscribe();
}
```

The output of the console logs, respectively, are:

```
// console log 1
0: {id: 1, userName: 'Jeff'}
1: {id: 2, userName: 'John'}

// console log 2
{id: 1, userName: 'Jeff'}

// console log 3
undefined
```

The issue is the third console log doesn't seem to be able to read the object property value even though THERE IS a value for userName. My question is what the heck and why???

Comment: *Very* strange! If you try `console.log(Object.keys(resolvedMembers[0])[1] === 'userName')` does it return `false`? If so then I'm guessing you have some special character in the property name you're receiving from the server, and that would be strange enough, but it not.... ‽‽

Comment: Yea, it returns false.

The endpoint looks like this:

const user = {
    id: result[0].id,
    userName: result[0].userName
};
res.send({
    user: user
});

Comment: What does `console.log(Object.keys(resolvedMembers[0])[1] )` return?

Comment: I figured it out - it had to do with the endpoint returning an array of strings rather than an array of objects. Will provide a further detailed explanation later.